# Passing around data

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4, react-props, react-state-management, react-state

My task is to create a SPA with an iTunes API.

I got my basic functionality done but it's not SPA yet, i wanted to implement react-router to handle the navigation.
However my components now need an extra parent. And i don't quite get it how can I pass the previously working data.

I don't want to inject huge block of code so i'd rather give you a Github link which is:
[My SPA](https://github.com/exitlol/OVITAS-SPA/tree/master/ovitas-spa/src)

But if you need the snippets let me know and i'll cover it.

Comment: Are you asking how to pass props down to child components, when using react-router-dom?

Comment: No and yeas at the same time.
My previously parent component is now a child so i have to pass the data that i'm getting to App so it can be handled by others but i don't really know the workaround